# play video playlist in Qt/Qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, playlist, qtmultimedia

I am making a simple playlist player on qml. I am using FolderListModel to read folders.
I want to run each video in turn. But my player only plays the first video, then the program crashes. My error is invalid property name `onStopped` in `Thong.qml`. My source code:

**main.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    color: "black"
    property bool onStart: true
    Thong {
        id: playlist
        mediaPlayer: player
        fm: FolderListModel {
            id: fm
            folder: "file:///home/pi/Documents/nhacmp4test"
            showDirs: false
            showDotAndDotDot: false
            nameFilters: ["*.wmv"]
            property bool ready: count > 0
            onReadyChanged: {if (player.status == MediaPlayer.NoMedia) {
                                playlist.setIndex(0);
                                player.play();
                            }}
        }
    }
    MediaPlayer { id: player }
    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: player
    }
}/*Thong.qml*/ Item{
id: a
property int index: 0
property MediaPlayer mediaPlayer
property FolderListModel fm
Component.onCompleted: {
    mainWindow.showNormal();
}    
function setIndex(i)
{
    index = i;
    console.log("setting index to: " + i);
    index %= fm.count;
    mediaPlayer.source = "file://" + fm.get(index,"filePath");
    console.log("setting source to: " + mediaPlayer.source);
}
function next()
{
    setIndex(index+1);        
}
Connections {
    target:  a.mediaPlayer
    onStopped: {
        if (a.mediaPlayer.status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia) {
            a.next();
            a.mediaPlayer.play();
            console.log("ok");
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: The error refers to `onClicked`, but that does not appear anywhere in the code that you provided. How can we help you?

Comment: sorry JarMan, it is "onStopped" in "Thong.qml"

Comment: Are you using Qt6? Qt5's `MediaPlayer` has a signal called `stopped`, but Qt6 does not.

Comment: I am using Qt5 version 5.11

Comment: my program can play the first video in the file, subsequent videos fail

Comment: I can only theorize, but I think you must actually be using Qt6. That's the only reason I can see why MediaPlayer wouldn't have a stopped signal.

Comment: I am using Qt 5.11 in Rasbperry Pi4. I guess the "Connection" part is calling the wrong syntax, but I still can't figure it out